# How to get result of form submission with jQuery Form Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

How can I get status code (200, 400, 404 etc.) at `showResponse` below:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    var options = { 
       success: showResponse
    };
    $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
      if (responseText == 'ok') { // status code to be used instead
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the jQuery Ajax docs:

statusCode(added 1.5)Map
Default: {}

A map of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the response has the corresponding code. For example, the following will alert when the response status is a 404:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback.

According to the jQuery form docs you can pass any of the standard $.ajax options to ajaxForm.

Comment: thanks. Should I add that `statusCode: {...}` to `options` list?

Comment: Yes, so the function defined will fire for the associated status code. In the above example when the Ajax request is a 404 it will alter the `page not found` message. So for success, you could define a callback for status code 200. Hope this helps!